# Pointer inside struct appears to change when struct is passed by value to function

Tags: c

The problem concerns the cmps element of struct Variable.

```
typedef struct Variable {
    struct Variable *cmps[2];
    double (*d_op)(void **a, struct Variable b);
    double val;
} Variable;

Variable new_var(double a)
{
    Variable v;
    v.cmps[0] = NULL;
    v.cmps[1] = NULL;
    v.d_op = NULL;
    v.val = a;
    return v;
}

Variable vs_mult(Variable a, Variable b)
{
    Variable v = new_var(0.0);
    v.cmps[0] = &a;
    v.cmps[1] = &b;
    
    v.d_op = &d_mult;

    return v;
}

int var_same(Variable a, Variable b)
{
    if ((a.cmps[0] == b.cmps[0]) && (a.cmps[1] == b.cmps[1]))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

double derivative(Variable a, Variable b)
{
    printf("(a.cmps)[0]->val: %lf; (a.cmps)[1]->val: %lf\n", (a.cmps)[0]->val, (a.cmps)[1]->val);
    if (var_same(a, b))
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    if (a.cmps[0] == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return a.d_op(a.cmps, b);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Variable x = new_var(2.0);
    Variable y = new_var(5.0);
    Variable z = vs_mult(x, y);
    eval(&z);
    
    printf("(z.cmps)[0]->val: %lf; (z.cmps)[1]->val: %lf\n", (z.cmps)[0]->val, (z.cmps)[1]->val);
    printf("%lf\n", derivative(z, x));
}
```

When the above program is executed the immediate output is this:

```
(z.cmps)[0]->val: 2.000000; (z.cmps)[1]->val: 5.000000  
(a.cmps)[0]->val: 2.000000; (a.cmps)[1]->val: 10.000000
```

Why is `(a.cmps)[1]->val` not equal to `(z.cmps)[1]->val`   ?

Comment: `v.cmps[0] = &a;` and `v.cmps[1] = &b;` assign the addresses of function parameters, which are local to the function. They are copies of the arguments, and the parameters cease to exist when the function returns. That renders the addresses invalid. If you want `vs_mult` to return an object containing pointers to `x` and `y`, then you must pass it pointers to `x` and `y`. You would have to change its declaration to `Variable vs_mult(Variable *a, Variable *b)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Why is (a.cmps)[1]->val not equal to (z.cmps)[1]->val ?" --> they point to different objects: `a` to some now invalid address (after `vs_mult()` returned) and `z` in `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `eval` is doing but there is something very dangerous in your code:

```
Variable vs_mult(Variable a, Variable b)
{
    Variable v = new_var(0.0);
    v.cmps[0] = &a;
    v.cmps[1] = &b;
    
    v.d_op = &d_mult;

    return v;
}
```

Note that function parameters `a` and `b` are local variables and their lifetime ends when `vs_mult` returns. Thus values in `cmps` are dangling pointer. Using their values (what `eval` likely does) invokes undefined behaviour.

To fix this the `vs_mult` should take *pointers* to variables.

```
Variable vs_mult(Variable *a, Variable *b)
{
    Variable v = new_var(0.0);
    v.cmps[0] = a;
    v.cmps[1] = b;
    ...
}
```

However, now the caller is responsible for assuring that lifetime of both variables encapsulates life of value returned by `vs_mult`.

Alternatively, you can try reference counting.

Comment: Does the same problem also apply to function `new_var()`? It looks to me as though it does not allocate any storage for a new variable, but just returns the address of a local variable which will go out of scope. Shouldn't `new_var()` contain a `malloc()` call?

Comment: @DavidHoadley, No. `new_var` returns a **copy** of a local variable. It is fine

Comment: Ah, yes. I must have been seeing an `&` operator where there isn't one!